# Get the closest element from a list of dictionaries based on a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to extract the most close element when counting backwards from a list of dicts based on a variable `utime`.  If `utime` is less than `uid.time`, it should not print anything.

I have created below script which does the work but doesn't seem to be efficient or foolproof as I have a preset value `dif = 999999`. How to get rid of this and make this foolproof? Also if `utime` is less than any of the `uid.time` value, it should not print anything.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
utime = 172200
uid = [
    {
      "id": 52,
      "time": 172100
    },
    {
      "id": 58,
      "time": 172120
    },
    {
      "id": 33,
      "time": 172153
    },
    {
      "id": 75,
      "time": 172150
    },
    {
      "id": 73,
      "time": 172210
    }
  ]

dif = 999999
ind = 0
for indx,i in enumerate(uid):
  tDiff = utime - i['time']
  if (tDiff > 0 and tDiff < dif):
    dif = tDiff
    ind = indx

print(uid[ind])
```

Expected Output (which I am getting anyway)

```json
{'id': 33, 'time': 172153}
```

Comment: The different between the utime 172200 and your expected output (172153) is not minimal. The last value (172210) only differs by 10. Can you please better explain your question?

Comment: Now I see, you want the difference to be positive too... Any logic behind setting dif to 999999?

Comment: the most close element when counting backwards from ```utime``` to ```uid.time```

Comment: if only closest between utime and uid.time. It just only `ind = uid.index(min(uid, key=lambda item: utime - item["time"]))` and result is `print(uid[ind])`

Comment: You say you want the closest *element*. Why do you keep it's index instead? Do you actually need the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `min` on the list with a key function that returns a tuple of whether or not the diff is non-positive, and the diff itself:

```
min(uid, key=lambda d: ((diff := utime - d['time']) <= 0, diff))
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/gDKJ6A

EDIT: If you want to avoid printing anything when therer is no entry in `uid` whose `time` is less than `utime`, you can use a generator expression to filter out unwanted entries before calling `min` with a default value of `None`:

```
if closest := min(
    ((diff, d) for d in uid if (diff := utime - d['time']) > 0),
    default=None
):
    print(closest[1])
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/4xAPJf

Comment: If ```utime``` is less than any of the ```uid.time```, it should not print anything. How can we achive this?

Comment: I've updated the answer accordingly then.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the code a bit, you can use a lambda function, even though this sacrifices a bit in terms of the readability of your code. Instead of the for loop and such, you can use this:

```
closest_user = min(uid, key=lambda x: abs(utime - x['time']) if utime > x['time'] else float('inf'))
```

Here, you can use the min function to identify the element in `uid` with the closest positive time difference to `utime`.

Furthermore, instead of using `dif = 999999`, you can specify `dif` to be infinity: `dif = float('inf')`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a minimum difference out of all positive differences. The simplest way is to first filter out the negative differences and then find the minimum. There is a built-in function for the minimum:`min`.

To make it even simpler, have a helper function:

```
def time_diff(item):
    return utime - item['time']
```

Then simply:

```
filtered = [x for x in uid if time_diff(x) > 0]
result = min(filtered, key=time_diff)
```

Answer (score -2):

If I am getting your question right, You want to find the dict with the time closest to utime.
You can keep the initial tDiff equal to utime and use abs for the difference.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
    utime = 172200
    uid = [
        {
          "id": 52,
          "time": 172100
        },
        {
          "id": 58,
          "time": 172120
        },
        {
          "id": 33,
          "time": 172153
        },
        {
          "id": 75,
          "time": 172150
        },
        {
          "id": 73,
          "time": 172210
        }
      ]

    dif = 172200
    ind = 0
    for indx,i in enumerate(uid):
      tDiff = abs(utime - i['time'])
      if (tDiff < dif):
        dif = tDiff
        ind = indx

    print(uid[ind])
```